# Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object in jboss with openJdk

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to start my **jboss** in window after providing the below details in standalone.conf.bat file but getting below error. Please suggest.

> JBoss Bootstrap Environment   JBOSS_HOME:
>   "jboss-eap-7.2.4.1\jboss-eap-7.2.4" JAVA: "C:\Program
>   Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.232.09-hotspot\bin\java"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): adding error details and usage scenario would help answering it.

Comment: getting above error after prroviding the JAVA _OPTS value as below

 JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xbootclasspath:%JBOSS_HOME%/modules/jboss-modules.jar

Comment: Sorry, for me it's still unclear. But maybe: it cannot find classpath for java? Check your setup, including `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: It would really help if we could see the actual error, including the stack trace.